# Find aggregate time that each process is unhealthy

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find the aggregate time each distinct process_name is unhealthy with sql as it is the only language I know. FALSE indicates a process is unhealthy until it switches to TRUE. If the process ends on False, I assume it is unhealthy until the end time in query.

The desired output would be something like: (process_name=A 4seconds |process_name=B 'x seconds')

| ts | process_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-30 09:30:00.856839-04 | A | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:30:00.856839-04 | A | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:30:05.857945-04 | A | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:30:05.857945-04 | A | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:30:14.58143-04 | B | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:30:19.581629-04 | B | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:07.383898-04 | C | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:07.383898-04 | C | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:12.385355-04 | C | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:12.385355-04 | C | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:16.562974-04 | D | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:51.606147-04 | E | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:51.606147-04 | E | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:53.481923-04 | Z | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:53.481923-04 | Z | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:53.737522-04 | X | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:53.737522-04 | X | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:56.6067-04 | E | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:56.6067-04 | E | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:58.482162-04 | Z | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:58.482162-04 | Z | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:58.73768-04 | X | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:32:58.73768-04 | X | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:33:41.574388-04 | D | true |
| 2022-06-30 09:33:52.562954-04 | F | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:33:52.562954-04 | F | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:33:57.988884-04 | G | false |
| 2022-06-30 09:33:57.988884-04 | G | false |

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: This seems like a Gaps & Islands problem. The traditional solution should apply.